# Reading from file and writing into another file using strtok and arrays

Tags: c, file-io, strtok

I have a project regarding C language using the `strtok` function. I'm reading the file with the while loop, and I'm continuously tokenizing words  from sentences using delimiters " " (blank space). As I am reading the file, if I encounter words that I have specified with if statements in the file A, I have to write specific lines to a file B (expansion of macroprocessors). The problem is that whenever I am trying to read from file A and respectively write each line in the file B I am only getting the last line from the file A, where I need to check each line and write one by one.

```
while(fgets(str,100,fp) != NULL){
    fgets(str,100,fp);
    if (str[0] == '@')
    {
        char *array[300];
        char *p = strtok (str," \n");
        while (p != NULL)  //tokenize the words, and save into array
        {
            array[i++] = p;
            p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
        if (!strcmp(array[0],"@def"))  // if the very first word encountered in the line is @def, write the words below into the file B
        {
            fprintf(fptr2, "define %s %s\n",array[1],array[2]);
        } //defining a global variable
        else if (!strcmp(array[0],"@mat"))// if the very first word encountered in the line is @mat, write the words below into the file B
        {
            fprintf(fptr2, "int %s[%s][%s]\n",array[1],array[2],array[3]); 
        }//defining a 2 dimensional array with dimensions MxN
    }
}
```

---

If the file A contains these lines:

```
@mat A N M
@def N 100
```

the file B will have this line written only:

```
define N 100
```

but it should have

```
int A[N][M]
define N 100
```

---

Similarly, if the file A contains these lines:

```
@def N 100
@mat A N M
```

the file B will have this line written here:

```
int A[N][M]
```

but it should have

```
define N 100
int A[N][M]
```

Comment: Remove the second `fgets`.

Comment: @user3386109 when I remove it, the first line is written properly but the second line has got (random?) word inside. This is my file A :def N 100
mat A N M         and this is what is printed inside file B : define N 100

int A[N][mat]

Comment: I'm sure there are many other problems. (For example, you aren't checking that each line has the correct number of tokens.) But the second `fgets` guarantees that you'll skip half the lines in the file, which is the problem that you described.

Comment: If you're hoping that someone will fix all of your bugs for you, then you'll have better luck if you post a [mcve].

Comment: a line may have 2 or 3 tokens, how would I check which one has what number of tokens, and how would it help me? can you elaborate a bit more on this? Thanks.

Comment: You don't show code resetting `i` to `0` at the start of the loop, so you store new tokens at large indexes in `array` but access only tokens at indexes 0-3.  At minimum, add `i = 0;` before the inner `while` loop.